# Как правильно располагать название города в URL

Tags: seo

Как со стороны SEO правильней располагать название города в URL сайта? И почему?

С SEO не сталкивался, слышал, что разные под домены например в яндексе считаются как разные сайта, и это хорошо для индексирования. Но имеет ли смысл ради этого выносить города как под домен?

`gorod.site.ru` или `site.ru/gorod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для продвижения по регионам лучше использовать `gorod.site.ru` в том случае если у Вас возможен разный контент по городам - например где-то есть товар, где-то нет:

> Размещайте на поддомене контент отличный от содержимого основного
>   домена. Если содержимое будет полностью дублироваться или
>   незначительно различаться, то один из адресов будет признан неглавным
>   зеркалом другого. Таким образом, роботы Яндекса начнут воспринимать
>   два сайта как один. В результате сайт, признанный неглавным зеркалом,
>   перестанет участвовать в результатах поиска.

[Яндекс о представительствах в разных регионах](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/recommendations/regionality.html)

`gorod.site.ru` - в данном случае при правильной настройке каждый поддомен будет расцениваться ПС как отдельный сайт. В Яндекс метрике можно поставить каждый поддомен на отельный регион. Лучше для продвижения по нескольким регионам.

`site.ru/gorod` - в данном случае каждый ПС расценивает Ваш сайт как один. Хуже для продвижения по нескольким регионам, лучше по одному конкретному.

P.S.: кроме всего прочего Вы должны понимать, что чем больше поддоменов, тем больше времени Вы будете тратить на анализ данных.